# AngularJS module is not loaded

Tags: html, angularjs

I'm trying to use different AngularJS modules in different HTML-pages but only one is loaded (frankly, I think that just only one is loaded but the problem may be in something else). To put the logic of the example in a nutshell: 
index.html - main page with 2 panels: left hand sidebar menu and main panel that contains relevant info. Click on menu makes request to the server and redirects data responded to relevant HTML that is in main panel.

Please find the code below:

**index.html (page that contains all views)**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="indexPageModule">
<head lang="en">
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Navigation Panel</title>
    <link href="/resources/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
    <link href="/resources/css/bootstrap-theme.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
    <link href="/resources/css/index-style.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
    <script src="/resources/js/angular.js"></script>
    <script src="/resources/js/angular-route.js"></script>
    <script src="/resources/js/index_page_module.js"></script>
    <base href="/">
</head>
<body ng-controller="indexPageRootController">
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div id="static-header" class="row">
        <nav role="navigation" class="navbar navbar-static-top custom-navbar row-bottom-margin">
        </nav>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div id="navigation-panel" class="col-lg-2 sidebar">
            <ul class="nav nav-list" ng-repeat="item in treeNavigationMenu">
                <li><label class="tree-toggler nav-header">{{item.parent}}</label>
                    <ul class="nav nav-list tree" ng-repeat="child in item.children">
                        <li><a href="{{child.urlPattern}}" ng-click="requestMainPanelData(child.urlPattern)">{{child.childName}}</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <div id="main-panel" class="col-lg-10 main-panel" ng-view>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

**index_module.js**

```
angular.module("indexPageModule", ['ngRoute'])
    .config(function($routeProvider, $locationProvider){
        $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
        $routeProvider.when("/limits_list", {
            templateUrl: "resources/static/limits_list.html"
        }).when("/limits_upload", {
            templateUrl: "resources/static/limits_upload.html"
        }).when("/exposures_list", {
            templateUrl: "resources/static/exposures_list.html"
        }).when("/exposures_upload", {
            templateUrl: "resources/static/exposures_upload.html"
        }).when("/breaches_list", {
            templateUrl: "resources/static/breaches_list.html"
        }).otherwise({
            templateUrl: "resources/static/default_main_page.html"
        })
    })
    .provider("navigationPanelRequestService", function(){
        return {
            $get : function($http) {
                return {
                    requestJson : function(pageUrl){
                        $http.get(pageUrl).success(function(response){
                            return response.data;
                        });
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    })
    .service("sharedMainPageData", function(){
        var sharedData;
        return {
            getMainPageData : function(){
                return sharedData;
            },
            setMainPageData : function(mainPageJson){
                sharedData = mainPageJson;
            }
        }
    })
    .controller("indexPageRootController", function($scope, $http, $document, navigationPanelRequestService, sharedMainPageData){
        $scope.treeNavigationMenu = {};
        $scope.requestMainPanelData = function(pageUrl){
            var retrievedData = navigationPanelRequestService.requestJson(pageUrl);
            sharedMainPageData.setMainPageData(retrievedData);
        };
        angular.element($document).ready(function(){
            $http.get("/navigation_menu/navigation_tree.json")
                .success(function(response){
                    $scope.treeNavigationMenu = response;
                });
        });
});
```

**limits_list.html (the page that should display JSON retrieved from server)**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="limitsListModule">
<head lang="en">
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Limits List</title>
    <link href="/resources/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
    <link href="/resources/css/bootstrap-theme.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
    <link href="/resources/css/index-style.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
    <script src="/resources/js/angular.js"></script>
    <script src="/resources/js/angular-route.js"></script>
</head>
<body ng-controller="limitsListController">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">{{limitsGridData.gridData}}</div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

**limits_list_module.js (the module that is supposed to be processed model for limits_list.html)**

```
angular.module("limitsListModule", ['indexPageModule'])
    .controller("limitsListController", function($scope, sharedMainPageData){
        $scope.limitsGridData = function(){
            if (angular.isDefined(sharedMainPageData.getMainPageData())){
                var jsonData = sharedMainPageData.getMainPageData();
                console.log("Retrieved data is here - " + jsonData.gridData);
                return jsonData;
            }
        }
    });
```

I tried to debug JS-side - as a result JSON is retrieved from server and is stored in **sharedMainPageData**(index_page_module.js) service. This **sharedMainPageData** should be available in **limitsListController** of the **limitsListModule** but it doesn't. More over it is not debugged. Even if I try to put incorrect controller name in ng-controller directive on limit_list.html then nothing happens (but an exception should be thrown). So I think the problem is in module bootstraping. 
What I tried to solve the problem:

- I tried to load module explicitly through angular.bootstrap()
- I tried to define module in limit_list.html instead of separated
  .js-file
- I tried to play with server call by using different aproaches:
  callbacks and promise-object

Internet search didn't helped. I'm really new in AngularJS and think that problem is trivial but due to lack of experience I can't solve it. If you have any ideas what is wrong with my code please let me know. Thanks.

Comment: are you including limits_list_module.js in the html?

Answer (score 1):

change `<div class="row">{{limitsGridData.gridData}}</div>` to call the function like this `<div class="row">{{limitsGridData().gridData}}</div>`
see an example of the difference here http://codepen.io/mkl/pen/YqBRay/

Comment: When I click on menu to request a page with data there are only 2 records in the console: "XHR finished loading: GET http://localhost:8081/limits_list and "XHR finished loading: GET http://localhost:8081/resources/static/limits_list.html. I tried to log when data comes up in limitsListController (take a look at the limitsListModule) but console is empty

Comment: Thanks, but it didn't help too. I tried to call "limitsListModule" from "indexPageModule" to throw exception if module is not loaded but nothing has happened. That is really strange.

Comment: Add console.log statements to limitsListController before the limitsGridData to make sure the controller is getting loaded.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/111459/discussion-between-michael-and-aime).

Answer (score 0):

The soulution was to:

-inject **limitsListModule** when defining **indexPageModule** and describe controller at

```
$routeProvider.when("/limits_list", {
        templateUrl: "resources/static/limits_list.html",
        controller: "limitsListController"
```

-to retrieve JSON correctly from server through async-call I had to correct $http-call a little:

```
.provider("navigationPanelRequestService", function(){
        return {
            $get : function($http) {
                return {
                    requestJson : function(pageUrl){
                        return $http.get(pageUrl);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    })

.controller("indexPageRootController", function($scope, $http, $document, navigationPanelRequestService, sharedMainPageData){
        $scope.treeNavigationMenu = {};
        $scope.requestMainPanelData = function(pageUrl){
            asyncRequestResult.then(function(response){
                sharedMainPageData.setMainPageData(response.data);
            },
            function(error){
                console.error("Sorry mate the shit has happened" + error.status);
                console.error("Sorry mate the shit has happened" + error.statusText);
            });
        };
```